# Creating a Mongoose BulkWrite Plugin

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm struggling with the bulkWrite operation. I'm trying to create a bulk of operations that upsert documents in my collection. For each document created a plugin is utilised.

```
const documents = [];
const count = 1000;
for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    documents.push(
        {
            updateOne:
            {
                filter: { itemId: i },
                update: { $set: { name: i } },
                upsert: true
            }
        }
    );
}
await MyModel.bulkWrite(documents);
```

Each document needs to have an updated at date for when the document as either created or updated. For that I use a plugin.

```
const plugin = function updateAtPlugin(schema: any, options: any) {
    schema.add({ updatedAt: Date });
    schema.post('updateOne', function (next: any) {
        this.updatedAt = new Date;
        next();
    });
    if (options && options.index) {
        schema.path('updatedAt').index(options.index);
    }
};
export default plugin;
```

This plugin is then used before the model is created.

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';
import updatedAtPlugin from './update-plugin';
const MySchema: Schema = new Schema({
    itemId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true
    },
    attributes: Object
});
MySchema.plugin(updatedAtPlugin);

const MyModel: any = model('my-name', MySchema);
export { MyModel };
```

In addition to the bulkWrite function I've also tried initializeUnorderedBulkOp in combination with find.upsert().updateOne().

In both cases the plugin is not working.

I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance

**------- EDIT ------**

I'd like to elaborate on my use case. The goal is to have a flag set as true for all new and updated documents and utilising a mongoose plugin to do so.

```
const plugin = function updated(schema: any, options: any) {
    schema.post('updateOne', function (next: any) {
        this.flag = true
        next();
    });
    if (options && options.index) {
        schema.path('flag').index(options.index);
    }
};
export default plugin;
```

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';
import updated from './updated-plugin';
const MySchema: Schema = new Schema({
    itemId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true
    },
    attributes: Object,
    flag: {
       type: Boolean, 
       default: true
    }
});
MySchema.plugin(updated);

const MyModel: any = model('my-name', MySchema);
export { MyModel };
```

The reason why is because the bulkWrite doesn't send back the `upserted` documents. It only returns a modified count. I'd like to execute a query `MySchema.find({flag: true})` loop through the result, do some magic and then `set the flag to false` for each processed item.

In addition to a plugin I've also tried `setDefaultsOnInsert` and `setOnInsert`. Unfortunately without success.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a custom plugin, mongoose has that built in.

Adding `{ timestamps: true }` as a second argument to your schema adds `createdAt` and `updatedAt` automatically to all your documents.

```
const MySchema: Schema = new Schema({
    itemId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true
    },
    attributes: Object
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortionaltly this is not a solution for me. By setting timestamps to true all my document in the bulkWrite will update and I want to separate the updated documents from the not updates ones. So maybe I should change my example. I'd like to create a plugin that sets an updated flag to true when the document is inserted or updated. Is that possible?

Comment: It still is not clear to me what you're trying to achieve.

settings `timestamps` to `true` should add `updatedAt` field whether your document is updated or not.

"I want to separate the updated documents from the not updates ones."
Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I've updated my post I hope it's more clear like this. Cheers

Comment: One more thing. If you have 1000 items added to your list and timestamps = true the count modified is always 1000 because all items are updated even though the only thing that updated is the actual timestamp itself. For me that's a problem because I just want to know which items out of a 1000 updated.

Comment: I think I understand the issue now. This is a known issue(?) in mongoose and can't currently be done, because mongoose doesn't know what the document looks like in the database, therefore it always sends an `updatedAt` whenever you're trying to update a document, whether it has changes or not.
Please refer to this GitHub issue for more information: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6861